# HTTPS connections for Revive (formely Openx)

Tags: https, openx

I have installed Revive Adserver 3.0.2 (formely Openx Adserver) and everything works fine.

But, only if my website its accessed using standard conexion (http).
If my website its accessed usin https connection no banner are served by Revive.

No error, no logs for Apache or Revive for any sort of error.

I've tried everyting I know to find the problem, but with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Try going to the `var` subfolder in your revive installation. There you can find a file `your.domain.here.conf.php`.

For me things started to work when I set the option `requireSSL=1`.

Oh, and have you checked that your https page only uses banners provided through https? Firefox does not load "acitve mixed content" since Firefox 23 so if you put your banners on your page with a `<script>`tag, your revive server won't even see a request if you are on an https site which loads banners via http.
See this link for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent